# How to check user location provided by WIFi or GPS

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

CLLocationManager Class provide location by GPS, WIFI or cellular, is there any way to check location provided by WIFI.
I know CLLocationManager class used GPS, WIFI on the basis of desiredAccuracy property.

Comment: You can check the `horizontalAccuracy` property of the locations you receive.  More accurate locations (10m or less) will definitely be from GPS.  Less accurate locations may or may not be from GPS.  Basically, you can't know definitively how the location was determined.

Answer (score 1):

GPS location readings show non negative speed. WiFi and cell tower triangulation locations have speed set to -1.

Comment: you say that based on what? Any documentation for that?